# Write command line variable into text file

Tags: windows, shell, scripting, command

I've got as far as I can with this one, but struggling at the last hurdle.

I am attempting to get the uptime of my Windows 7 machine, load it into a variable, trim the current time from the left part of the variable and then write it back from a variable into a .txt file.

All works just fine, except I do not know how to write the variable back into a text file.

Here is what I have:

```
c:
cd/
uptime.exe > uptime.txt
set /p str=<uptime.txt
echo.%str%
set str=%str:~-16%
echo.%str%
```

Now the last echo line displays exactly what I want, but how do I write that variable back into uptime.txt?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: `echo %str% > uptime.txt`?

Comment: Man, I'm sure I tried that!! Do you want to list it as an answer and I'll accept it? Jeeeez i feel dumb now!

Thanks!

Comment: cant you write that output in different file and read new file?

Comment: `>uptime.txt echo %str%` <--- that method eliminates the need for trailing spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply redirect standard output to the file of your choice to achieve your goal. For example:

```
echo %<name of environment variable>% > <path of file>
echo %str% > uptime.txt
```